# C# number format: leading plus sign AND spaces

Tags: c#, number-formatting

What I'm trying to do is to display numbers in a finance report like this:

```
+   5000
+    176
-  10000
- 620230
```

So I need to print out number that's 6 digits long, with leading sign.

I tried to combine leading sign with leading spaces like this: `String.Format("{0,7:+#;-#;+0}", value);`, but turns out it gives me:

```
   +5000
    +176
  -10000
 -620230
```

Is there anyway to use String.Format to get the output I want?

*Edit*: I understand that I could make my own format function to achieve that result, and I did use one. I'm asking out of curiosity with `String.Format` to see if it's could be done.

Comment: I strongly *suspect* there isn't. I'd probably just write a method to format it by extracting the sign and then formatting the absolute value with appropriate padding separately. That will probably take less time to write than experimenting with a lot of string formats.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need some trick to combine the parts (the sign and the number). Here is how it's done:

```
string.Format("{0:+;-;+}{0,7:#;#;0}",someNumber);
```

`{0,7:#;#;0}` will format the number so that only the absolute value is displayed. While the first part `{0:+;-;+}` will just display the sign accordingly to the value. You can make your own method to wrap that line of code as for convenience.

Comment: If someone said they "knew C++", would you expect them to see this format string and know what it does? If someone was "familiar with C++" and saw this format string, what's the most efficient path you think they could follow toward figuring out what it actually does?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that returns a formatted string. It's quite self explanatory.

```
static string FormatFinancialNumber(int number) {
    string sign = number < 0 ? "-" : "+"; // decide the sign
    return sign + Math.Abs(number).ToString().PadLeft(7); // Make the number part 7 characters long
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(FormatFinancialNumber(1));
Console.WriteLine(FormatFinancialNumber(-12));
Console.WriteLine(FormatFinancialNumber(123));
Console.WriteLine(FormatFinancialNumber(-1234));
Console.WriteLine(FormatFinancialNumber(12345));
```

Output:

```
+      1
-     12
+    123
-   1234
+  12345
```

Comment: Elegant solution +1

Comment: Thanks, this is the function I'm using too. I'm simply asking the question out of curiosity with String.Format. Perhaps I should make that clear in the question.

Comment: @AVAVT King King's answer uses `string.Format`. But to me, readability is more important.